# Horizontal orientation of DataGrid in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-4.0, orientation, silverlight-toolkit

I want to change the orientation of the datagrid to horizontal in Silverlight 4. In other words, I want to display the headers on the left hand side and the values corresponding to it on right hand side.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataGrid does not support horizontal item scrolling.

One very mad idea would be to use the Toolkit's `LayoutTransformer` to rotate the whole grid by 90degrees then template all the headers and cells with a `LayoutTransfomer` to rotate their contents back.   One issue (likely of many, if it's even possible) would be the scrollbar would appear on the top rather than the bottom.  You might be able to sort that out with further templating.

Comment: can I use DataForm and somehow hide the buttons??